# python regex to select everything before and after a particular string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to apply regex on one of the columns in pandas dataframe, this column has text data in it, I am trying to extract a specific block. This is a sample of how my data will look like,

```
Patient Name :
NHI:  ABC2134
DOB:  10/03/1737

Patient Referred from: WTH ABC
Exam performed at:  XYZ Hospital Radiology
Reference:   ABCADAFAD
Date of exam:   12/11/2019
Examination(s) included in this report:
 CT Head

INDICATION:
Fall some time ago with ataxia since. Recent admission with 
tachybrady syndrome.
```

I am trying to extract text from the beginning of the given string up to the first blank line following the first line containing 'Patient Referred from'., the entities may or may not appear in same order except the "Patient Referred from" which will always be the first entity, but there wont be any empty line until that entire block is finished. I have tried this below one,

```
import re
def extract_patient_details(s):

    match = re.search('(?s)Patient Referred(.*?)(?:(?:\r*\n){2})', s)
    return match.group(0)

extract_patient_details(s)
```

The above snippet works fine and gives me this output:

```
Patient Referred from: WTH ABC
Exam performed at:  XYZ Hospital Radiology
Reference:   ABCADAFAD
Date of exam:   12/11/2019
Examination(s) included in this report:
 CT Head
```

But what I want is:

```
Patient Name :
NHI:  ABC2134
DOB:  10/03/1737

Patient Referred from: WTH ABC
Exam performed at:  XYZ Hospital Radiology
Reference:   ABCADAFAD
Date of exam:   12/11/2019
Examination(s) included in this report:
 CT Head
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.DOTALL` plays an important role in your case.

```py
def extract_patient_details(s):
    match = re.search(r'^(.*Patient Referred.*?)(?:\r?\n){2}', s, re.DOTALL)
    return match.group(1)
```

In `pandas`, you can use `extract` method as well.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'diagnosis': '''Patient Name :
NHI:  ABC2134
DOB:  10/03/1737

Patient Referred from: WTH ABC
Exam performed at:  XYZ Hospital Radiology
Reference:   ABCADAFAD
Date of exam:   12/11/2019
Examination(s) included in this report:
 CT Head

INDICATION:
Fall some time ago with ataxia since. Recent admission with 
tachybrady syndrome.'''}
])

pat = re.compile(r'^(.*Patient Referred.*?)(?:\r?\n){2}', re.DOTALL)
df_extracted = df.diagnosis.str.extract(pat, expand=True)
```

---

#### Answer to the OP's comment:

In order to extract the latter part additionally, you can write code like this:

##### Using your original function:

```py
def extract_patient_details(s):
    match = re.search(r'^(.*Patient Referred.*?)(?:\r?\n){2}(.*)$', s, re.DOTALL)
    return match.groups()
```

##### Using pandas:

```py
pat = re.compile(r'^(.*Patient Referred.*?)(?:\r?\n){2}(.*)$', re.DOTALL)
df_extracted = df.diagnosis.str.extract(pat, expand=True)
```

Comment: In case, if I want to extract everything except the above pattern, how can I do that? In the above example, if I want everything after that empty line starting from "INDICATION" until the end of the document, how can I get that?

Comment: You could avoid the need for a capture group with `r'^.*\bPatient Referred\b.*?(?=(?:\r?\n){2})\r?\n'`.

Comment: It makes sense. I didn't come up with this. Thank you for pointing it out to simplify the code.

Answer (score 1):

To match the part of string `s` that is of interest, write:

```
rgx = r'[\s\S]*\bPatient Referred from\b.*\r?\n(?:.+\r?\n)*'
```

```
re.search(rgx, s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z1MTON/1)

To obtain the part of the string that is not matched (including one or more leading empty lines), write:

```
re.sub(rgx, '', s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q88Qyg/1)

This regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
[\s\S]*                # match zero or more characters 
\b                     # word boundary
Patient Referred from  # match literal
\b                     # word boundary
.*\r?\n                # match rest of line
(?:                    # begin non-capture group
  [^\r\n]+             # match one or non-line terminator chars
  \r?\n                # match a line terminator
)*                     # end non-capture group and execute 
                       # it zero or more times
```

`[\s\S]` matches all whitespace characters and all non-whitespace error, so it is a way to match all characters, including, but unlike `.`, line terminators. `[\w\W]` does the same thing. `\r?` is needed for files created by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your regex is:

```
(?s)Patient Referred(.*?)(?:(?:\r*\n){2})
```

It's matching everything you told it to - your string start looks for "Patient Referred" and not Patient name, ie everything between patient referred + ct head. Try this instead:

```
match = re.search('(?s)(Patient Name).*?( CT Head)', s)
```

output:

```
Patient Name :
NHI:  ABC2134
DOB:  10/03/1737

Patient Referred from: WTH ABC
Exam performed at:  XYZ Hospital Radiology
Reference:   ABCADAFAD
Date of exam:   12/11/2019
Examination(s) included in this report:
 CT Head
```

Entire code:

```
import re


def extract_patient_details(s):

    match = re.search('(?s)(Patient Name).*?( CT Head)', s)
    return match.group(0)


s = """
Patient Name :
NHI:  ABC2134
DOB:  10/03/1737

Patient Referred from: WTH ABC
Exam performed at:  XYZ Hospital Radiology
Reference:   ABCADAFAD
Date of exam:   12/11/2019
Examination(s) included in this report:
 CT Head

INDICATION:
Fall some time ago with ataxia since. Recent admission with 
tachybrady syndrome. 
"""

s = extract_patient_details(s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but "Patient Name" may or may not be present in all text, apologies if I was not clear, but "Patient Referred From" will always be there, thats why I am trying to use it in my pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `re.match(r'(?sm).+CT Head', st).group(0)`?

`(?sm)` turns ON [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) and [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)

We're using [re.match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) as we're matching from the beginning of the string

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I cant use "CT Head", it may or may not present in all text